# Running commands in a login shell in ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm trying to call some bash scripts in Ruby. When I use the backticks method, I get the error. I always get the error when running the script from a non-login shell. My code is:

```
output = `/root/script`
```

How can I run commands in a login shell and capture their output?

Comment: You could try this: `/bin/bash /root/script`

Comment: can you post the content of your script and also the error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a bash login shell, create one explicitly:

```
output = %x{ bash -lc "/root/script" }
```